# Mysql : how to synchronize 2 tables structures when adding new fields?

Tags: mysql

I have N database: 1 in development and N-1 in production with >50 fields.

I add new fields in devlopment. Then I add manually new fields to my production table.

Is there a way to synchronyze the structures : like add new fields if these do not exist ? (a lind of incremental update ?)
If I drop the table and create, I will also lose the data.

If I do copy of old table and then try to insert data, I will get a sql error telling me that old table and new tables do not have the same number of columns

```
insert into newTable select * from oldTable; // error different number of fields in structure
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use command-line tool mysqldiff .

```
mysqldiff -d sql -changes-for=server2 \
--server1=username1:username1@host1 \
--server2=username2:password2@host2 \
your_database.your_table1:your_database.your_table2
```

This program will generate SQL commands to change structure of *your_table2* to be similar to *your_table1*.

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to specify set of columns which you want to insert and in what columns you want them:

```
insert into newTable (col1,col2,...,colN)
select toCol1, toCol2, ..., toColN from oldTable;
```

Comment: yes:: problem is that  my table is.. 80 fields and growing !

Comment: @yarek It's easy, you can get list of columns from meta-data, like table with column names of particular table. You could go even further and write procedure to generate lengthy parts (like columns list) of a query.